# Job responsibility has changed and I am not getting the help I need

Tags: united-states, startup

I was hired last November (startup company - US. Only 10 Employees) for my particular expertise in databases.

Two months ago, management hired my supervisor. It's just him and I now in charge of all database work. His expertise is not databases.

Two weeks ago, he asked me to start learning a new programming language as he had high priority assignments for me.

I am 100% committed but I have never done object-oriented programming. I am struggling. I went to his boss asking for a plan on what to focus my study on but all I got was "sure, I'll talk to him and we'll figure something out". Nothing happened.

Yesterday, he took away an assignment from me because I was taking too long (his words). I asked him to help me but to no avail. He's always been reticent...either he has a meeting to run to or he wants to know specifically what I don't understand (everything?)...even his body language seems off.

I emailed his boss again, emphasized I am committed and simply asked to go a training. The response I got  was "Understood - Thx" (verbatim).

Is it time to look for a new job?

Comment: This question is too broad, and you are also asking for advice on a choice.  I feel for you, but see if you can narrow the scope of this question so we can help.

Comment: See also [How can I ask my boss for training?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/24694/how-can-i-ask-my-boss-for-training)

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, I wouldn't wait for your boss to train you.  There is so much free stuff out there to get you a basic understanding of OOP that you can take the initiative and do it yourself on your off time.

It's a win-win for you if you do.  EITHER your boss and boss's boss will respect you for doing so, or it will be a great thing to speak to on an interview for your next job during the "tell me about yourself" phase of the interview.

"Well, I was hired to do databases and then was required to do OOP.  My immediate supervisor knew that I had no experience in OOP, but had confidence in my abilities.  The employer did not have the ability to send me to class at the time, so I studied at home after hours and brought myself up to speed"/

Use this to your advantage.  You cannot lose if you take the initiative.

Comment: Asking a database specialist to learn OOP dev is like asking an industrial engineer to start doing aerospace engineering. It is s a totally different profession.  What makes a good database person is at odds with what makes a good OOP developer.

Comment: @HLGEM It's never been a problem for me.